# Error when running the minimal example of shogun

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors, shogun

I installed shogun following the tutorial [shogun quick start](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/wiki/QUICKSTART) and tried [this](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/wiki/README_developer) simple example

However, when I run this:`g++ -lshogun minimal.cpp` 
I got this:

```
/tmp/ccAIVbZB.o: In function main:

minimal.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to shogun::init_shogun(void (*)(_IO_FILE*, char const*), void (*)(_IO_FILE*, char const*), void (*)(_IO_FILE*, char const*), void (*)(bool&, bool&))'
minimal.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference toshogun::exit_shogun()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And as is suggested, i ran `ldconfig` which gave the same output.

I have googled this question but got no helpful answer. Your kindly help will be definitely appreciated!

Comment: put `-lshogun` after `minimal.cpp`

Comment: And I wonder why? What's the difference between g++ -lshogun minimal.cpp -o minimal and g++ minimal.cpp -lshogun -o minimal ?

Comment: g++ defaults to only making one pass over the objects, and the first way it passes -lshogun before passing your object

Comment: Great Thanks ! Really helpful! ^_^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)